# Using dplyr to replace a vector of names with new names

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a problem that I have yet to think or find a way to use dplyr for that would think should be able elegantly solve.

Say I have an original data frame with names associated with each id.

```
original_data <- data.frame(id = 1:10, name = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And from there I have data frame with the names in the original data frame that I want to replace.

```
replacement_dataframe <- data.frame(old_name = c("a","b", "c"), 
                                    new_name = c("abra", "banana", "coconut"), 
                                    stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would normally do the operation I would like to use dplyr for but haven't figured it out yet like so,

```
original_data$name[original_data$name == "a"] <- "abra"
original_data$name[original_data$name == "b"] <- "banana"
original_data$name[original_data$name == "c"] <- "coconut"
```

Comment: Just do a `match` or a `left_join` in `dplyr` or with `data.table` `setDT(original_data)[replacement_dataframe,  name := new_name , on = .(name = old_name)]`

Comment: You can test my method , should be ok

Answer (score 3):

Cause I working both on `Python` and `R` , I will recommend this:

```
map=c("a"="abra","b"="banana","c"="coconut")

original_data$name[!is.na(map[original_data$name])]=map[original_data$name][!is.na(map[original_data$name])]


> original_data
   id    name
1   1    abra
2   2  banana
3   3 coconut
4   4       d
5   5       e
6   6       f
7   7       g
8   8       h
9   9       i
10 10       j
```

EDIT: @Damian's method, much more neat.

```
original_data %>% mutate(name = ifelse(name %in% names(map), map[name], name))
```

EDIT2 : For the `map` creation from @ycw

```
map <- replacement_dataframe$new_name
names(map) <- replacement_dataframe$old_name
```

Comment: I like the use of a named vector as a lookup. For improved readability I would use `ifelse` to implement the condition instead of subsetting: `original_data %>% mutate(name = ifelse(name %in% names(map),  map[name], name))`. Also, I would recommend generating the `map` vector programmatically, for convenience: `map <- replacement_dataframe$new_name` followed by `names(map) <- replacement_dataframe$old_name`

Comment: Nice approach. If you don't want to manually  type `a = "abra", ...` to create `map`, you can use `map <- replacement_dataframe$new_name', and then `names(map) <- replacement_dataframe$old_name`

Answer (score 2):

This should work now:

```
ind <- match(original_data$name, replacement_dataframe$old_name)
original_data$name[!is.na(ind)] <- replacement_dataframe$new_name[ind[!is.na(ind)]]
```

Comment: How would I get your method to work if the order of the new names aren't aligned with the order of the original data frame.  My fault for not making that part of the sample data.

Comment: It does! Thank you.  but if I change the order of rows in the original data frame it doesn't original_data <- data.frame(id = 10:1, name = letters[10:1], stringsAsFactors = F)

Comment: Oh yes, I did a terrible mistake. Will update my answer.

Comment: @cylondude Please try again.